# Caching IP Address for a Domain Name

Tags: node.js

How do I cache a IP address for a domain name in NodeJS to accelerate the app by avoiding the dns lookup everytime? Also set TTL for the caching so I can periodically lookup if IP for domain name has changed.

Comment: Your operating system should be managing this for you (e.g not doing a DNS lookup every time).  This is not a node.js setting, this would be an OS implementation setting (in your TCP stack).  You could, of course, take matters into your own hands and lookup the IP address once yourself and save the IP address and not use the domain name any more in your node.js calls.

Comment: So, Server's OS on which I deploy the app provides the functionality of caching the IP for domain name?

Comment: What server OS?  Also keep in mind that DNS records have a TTL (time to live) setting which should also come into play here.

Comment: On whatever server, where I deploy the app... That is supposed to take care of "Caching IP for Domain Name"? Is it what u mean to say in your previous comment?

Comment: OS level DNS caching varies by OS implementation.  Windows and Mac definitely cache DNS requests.  Apparently some Linux distributions do not cache unless other software is enabled or installed (to my surprise).  See [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/localhost-dns-cache) about Linux DNS caching.

Comment: You can also do the DNS lookup yourself and then hang onto the IP address for as long as you want: https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lookup-dns-cache

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/lookup-dns-cache.

Have encountered the same problem, so decided to solve it in a node way (by creating package :) ).